# Border Location on JQuery Div Height Change

Tags: jquery, user-interface

jsFiddle [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/vtex4/)

I'm toggling a div's height using JQuery 1.5.2, and it mostly seems to work fine.  However, the lower border line does not relocate when it grows, but it does relocate when it shrinks.

Same results for both Chrome and IE9 (I stopped trying other browsers after the first two, because they are my main targets, and are mostly compliant besides.)  What gives?

What I've tried:

- hiding and re-drawing the border
- different (newer) versions of jQuery
- `animate({height: x}, y)` instead of `css('height', x)`

Comment: something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/vtex4/3/

Comment: @Virendra the problem with that is that I've got this page where the designer put in a fixed height for the div, and I can't touch it or other things will break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code,

```
$("#siteMapToggle").click(function() {
    var temp = $(this).attr("srcAlt");
    $(this).attr("srcAlt", $(this).attr("src"));
    $(this).attr("src", temp);

    if ($("#fullmenu .menu_tbl").is(':visible')) {
        $("#fullmenu").css('height', '100px');
        $("#fullmenu .menu_tbl").hide();
    }
    else {

        $("#fullmenu .menu_tbl").show();
        $("#fullmenu").css('height', '267px');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vtex4/4/

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple behavior based on *overflow* css style and classes to show/hide border-bottom:

**JS**

```
$("#siteMapToggle").click(function() {

    $("#fullmenu .menu_tbl").toggle("fast", function() {
        $("#fullmenu").toggleClass('borderHide')
    });
```

});

**CSS**

```
#fullmenu{
    width:900px;
    border-top:3px solid #999;
    border-bottom:3px solid #999;
    overflow:auto
}

.borderHide {
    border-bottom:3px solid #999;
}
```

see full jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/vtex4/5/